# Error on mgo dependency when deploying go app to Heroku

Tags: heroku, go

I'm trying to deploy a Go App to Heroku, I'm using godeps for dependency management as their docs suggested.
But when I `git push heroku master` I get the following error telling that the file sasl.go doesn't exists.

```
remote: # github.com/grsouza/feeng-api/vendor/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/internal/sasl
remote: vendor/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/internal/sasl/sasl.go:15:24: fatal error: sasl/sasl.h: No such file or directory
remote:  // #include <sasl/sasl.h>
remote:                         ^
remote: compilation terminated.
remote: github.com/grsouza/feeng-api/vendor/github.com/onsi/gomega
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Go app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to limitless-ridge-36512.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/limitless-ridge-36512.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/limitless-ridge-36512.git'
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your vendored version of `gopkg.in/mgo.v2` updated?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use `godep save ./...` in your project?

If yes, delete the `Godep` and `vendor` directories and try to use `godep save`, without `./...`.

I do this and work for me.

Comment: The problem is that heroku automatically runs  `godep save ./...`

Answer (score 0):

Error tells sasl/sasl.h missing but not sasl.go. sasl.h header file is part of libsasl2-dev package which not installed on heroku and I don't know simple way to install it. To my mind you can try to find sasl headers on your local machine(most likely /usr/include/sasl)and copy to vendor/include/sasl in your local go app source. Then make them visible for CGO using heroku config vars doing

```
heroku config:set CGO_CFLAGS= -I/app/code/vendor/include/sasl
```

in heroku console, and than git push.
Also you can look for libsasl2-dev buildpack for heroku and try to use two buildpacks for your app with something like

```
heroku buildpacks:add heroku/some_libsasl2-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution (from https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo/issues/220#issuecomment-212658192):

- run `godep save ./...` (to create the vendor directory with all the dependencies)
- then re-run `godep save` without ./... (this will remove unused files)